# Optimizing hybrid_properties in SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a piece of working code but it is very inefficient, instead of a single query with a join. I get one initial query, followed by one query per row in the response.

I have to following scenario:

```
class Job(Base, SerializeMixin, JobInterface):
    __tablename__ = 'job_subjobs'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("job_groups.id"), nullable=False)

class Crash(Base, SerializeMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'crashes'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("job_subjobs.id", ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    job = relationship('Job', backref='Crash')

    @hybrid_property
    def job_identifier(self):
        return "{}:{}".format(self.job.group_id, self.job.id)
```

So given the above and I perform a query for all Crashes, It will perform one SELECT for all crashes. When I iterate and ask for **job_identifier** it will then do one separate SELECT for each crash.

```
    self.session.query(Crash).all()
```

Is there someway i can create a @hybrid_property referencing a different table and have it JOIN from the beginning and preload the expression?

I've experimented with @xxx.expression without success. If all else fails I can add another foreign key in Crash table, but I would like to avoid changing current data structure if possible.

Comment: Can this be accomplished with orm.column_property() ? Joining two columns form a different table to a new column_property?

Comment: This is accomplished through [eager loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-loader-strategies-lazy-loading-eager-loading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using:

```
jobs = relationship('Job', backref='Crash', lazy='joined')
```